# mongoose find and update nested object in an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Below is my mongoose schema.

An application can have multiple incidents and subscribers. Each incident can have multiple journal updates.

Application->incident(s)->journalupdate(s)

My goal is to allow users to update an incident detail in an application. Later add a journal update to an incident in the application.

```
const JournalUpdateSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    timeStamp: { type: Date, required: true },
    owner: { type: String },
    updateText: { type: String }
});

// Incident Schema
const IncidentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    incidentNum: { type: String, required: true },
    incidentPriority: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },        
    jounralUpdates: [JournalUpdateSchema]
});

//Subscriber Schema
const SubscriberSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    subscriberName: { type: String },
    subscriberMail: { type: String },
    subscriberPhone: { type: String }
});

// Application Schema
const ApplicationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    applicationName: { type: String, required: true },
    clusterName: { type: String, required: true },
    ragStatus: { type: String, required: true },
    incidents: [IncidentSchema],
    subscribers: [SubscriberSchema]
});
```

I have already tried Applications.Update(), Applications.findByIdAndUpdate() methods but I cannot reach the incident level to update.

can someone help me with this please? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't nest arrays within each other. Whatever the reason you think gave you an advantage is actually a "disadvantage". MongoDB cannot update beyond the "first" matched index of an array. In "nested" terms that means the "outer" array only, and can **never** determine the position of an inner array. Read the [positional `$` operator documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) and "flatten" your array into a single array, or move the elements to an external collection.

Comment: Thanks. If I move my sub documents into their own collections, how would I link them to my parent collection? In my case, how do I link a set of incidents to one application?

Comment: Too broad and far too selectively read. I did not say you "have to" move the data into different collections, but rather that the structure generally needs to be "flatter".  The reason being that "nesting arrays"  is bad practice and simply does not work in the way that you seemed to presume it does. So the structure here does not work. You would be better off asking "smaller questions" about "pieces" of the application design and gain a good picture rather than just modelling a whole thing and then having to work with the explanations of why each part is wrong. Here you learned to not nest

Comment: @NeilLunn, Thanks for the advice !!! I'll google how to work with multiple collections. If you have any pointers for best practices and a proper way to design schemas similar to my problem, please point me to. :)